# AsposeWords get rid of extra table height

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

I am having trouble trying to get rid of this extra space on my table using aspose words api.

Isn't there a function to use minimal space and extend cell height only when the text length reaches a limit ?

Currently, my table looks like this...

[image]

But I want the table to be build with no spaces like below:

[image]

What are the right properties to use and in which order ?

I am building the table with [DocumentBuilder](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/documentbuilder+overview).

These is my code :

```
Table table = builder.startTable();

        // Insert Column headers: 
        int hcolumn = 0;
        for (String column : columns) {
            builder.insertCell();
            builder.getFont().setBold(true);
            builder.getRowFormat().setHeadingFormat(true);
            builder.writeln(translateHeader(column, hcolumn));
            table.setBottomPadding(0);
            hcolumn++;
        }

        builder.endRow(); // End of Header
        builder.getRowFormat().clearFormatting();

        // Loop through the records, split comma seperated(per cell) and create
        // a "row" for each loop.
        for (String string : data) {
            List<String> result = Arrays.asList(string.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
            int column = 0;
            for (String string2 : result) {
                builder.insertCell();
                builder.getFont().setBold(false);
                builder.getRowFormat().setHeadingFormat(false);
                // translate and insert
                builder.writeln(translateData(string2, column));
                column++;
            }
            builder.endRow();

        }
        builder.endTable();
```

I added "setBottomPadding" to 0 which didnt help.

This is the generated document: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g10j3vz0c2dto91/GeneratedWord.docx?dl=0)
This is how i want it to be : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mnisqc8x1c8a1f8/Expected_GeneratedWord.docx?dl=0)

Comment: Perhaps, you can fix this problem by specifying 0 to Table.BottomPadding property. In case the problem still remains, please upload your **input** (_Aspose.Words generated DOCX file_) and **expected** Word documents on Dropbox and share the download links here for testing. We will investigate the issue on our end and provide you more information. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @AwaisHafeez hello ! Thank you for your reply. I just updated the question. I tried what you provided to no success. Please see the question for the document links attached as requested as well as the code used for generation. Hope to hear from u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documents, [`DocumentBuilder.WriteLn`](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words.documentbuilder/writeln/methods/1) does that: *Inserts a string and a paragraph break into the document*; so you just want to write the data without a paragraph break. Try to use `builder.write` instead of `builder.writeln` and see if it's working.

PS: You may already know that, but the `ln` at the end of the `write[ln]` stands for `line`, so it generally means that it will print/write adding a new line at the end of the text/data.

Comment: I was so blinded that i failed to see it ! thanks. Bounty well earned :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `builder.writeln(translateData(string2, column));` to `builder.write(translateData(string2, column));`

`writeln` adds a space(new line) at the bottom.